# Changing dropdownlist selected index in Gridview, conected (to getting value from) second DropDownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

My page which to do this:
[image]

I want to connect outside dropdown list to inside of gridview dropdownlist. When selec item from outside dropdownlist, must be change inside dropdown list item automaticaly. I've tried a lot thing to change. Can you give me help. Thanks.

My ASPX page.(Don't answer connected this code)

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView4" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"   
CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="Kimlik" GridLines="Horizontal"   
onrowdatabound="GridView4_RowDataBound" ForeColor="#333333" Visible="False">  
<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />  
<Columns>  
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Öd.Nu.">  
        <EditItemTemplate>  
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1x" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Kimlik") %>'></asp:TextBox>  
        </EditItemTemplate>  
        <ItemTemplate>  
            <asp:Label ID="Label1x" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Kimlik") %>'></asp:Label>  
        </ItemTemplate>  
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Öğrenci Adı Soyadı">  
        <EditItemTemplate>  
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2x" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("OgrenciAdiSoyadi") %>'></asp:TextBox>  
        </EditItemTemplate>  
        <ItemTemplate>  
            <asp:Label ID="Label2x" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("OgrenciAdiSoyadi") %>'></asp:Label>  
        </ItemTemplate>  
    </asp:TemplateField>  

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Odev Sonucu">  
        <EditItemTemplate>  
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3x" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>  
        </EditItemTemplate>  
        <ItemTemplate>  
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1x" runat="server">  
            </asp:DropDownList>  
        </ItemTemplate>  
    </asp:TemplateField> 

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Ödev Sonuç Açıklaması">  
        <EditItemTemplate>  
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4x" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SonucAciklama") %>'></asp:TextBox>  
        </EditItemTemplate>  
        <ItemTemplate>  
            <asp:Label ID="Label4x" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SonucAciklama") %>'></asp:Label>  
        </ItemTemplate>  
    </asp:TemplateField>  
</Columns>  

<EditRowStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" />

<FooterStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" />  
<HeaderStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />  
<PagerStyle BackColor="#666666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />  
<RowStyle BackColor="#E3EAEB" />  
<SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#C5BBAF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />  
<SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F8FAFA" />  
<SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#246B61" />  
<SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D4DFE1" />  
<SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#15524A" />  
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on Selected Index Change Event of Outer drop down add below code

```
protected void OurterDropDown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView.Rows)
            {
                DropDownList innerDropdown = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("innedDropedDOwnID");

                 innerDropdown .ClearSelection(); //making sure the previous selection has been cleared
                 innerDropdown .Items.FindByValue(OurterDropDown.SelectedValue).Selected = true;               

            }
}
```

Comment: When i try it didn't work. (I forgot to arrange AutoPostBack true for Outer dropdown) when i correct it my problem solved. Thanks a lot, thanks thanks. I've gave 4-5 hour for this. Thanks too stackoverflow. (this is firs stackoverflow experience)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set `AutoPostBack="true"` outside DropDownList and then try this code in RowDataBound event:

```
protected void GridView4_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    // check if your row is not a Header/Footer row
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // get Dropdownlist from gridview
        DropDownList DropDownList1x = e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList1x") as DropDownList;

        // ddlouter is your outside DropDownList
        DropDownList1x.Items.FindByValue(ddlOuter.SelectedValue).Selected = true; 
    }
}
```

Comment: What it gives for me. i can't understand.

(Before i send this question i filled both DropDownList from a  Table field)

1-just I want to fill all innerDropDownList like outher.
2-after user changing some inner DropDownLists, after than i will UPDATE table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: which thing you *can't understand*?